# Passing jquery search results to a page method

Tags: jquery, pagemethods

I have am using a sortable jQuery list.  I would like to send the results of that list to a webmethod for processing.

So my javascript is something like:

```
function ProcessSortableList() {
    var arr = {};

    arr[0] = "item1";
    arr[1] = "item2";
    PageMethods.TestMe(arr);
}
```

I then have a webmethod on the server side:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static String TestMe(String[] items)
    {
        ... Do stuff here ...
    }
```

The web method doesn't get called.  If I change the webmethod so it takes a single parameter ...

**TestMe(string item)**

... and then I call it with a single value

**PageMethods.Test('item1')**

everything works fine.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var arr = {}
```

to

```
var arr = new Array()
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question on why or what's incorrect, but worst case scenario you could send your array of strings just as a pipe delimited string.

```
var stuff = "item1|item2";
```

Send that over and just do

```
var strings = item.Split('|');
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Thanks Chris.